# How do regex for only numbers and skip letter e in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying do pincode validation using regex which takes only 6 numbers.

I am able to do validation for numbers but it is also accepting letter "e" as well which I want to skip.

Regex code: `pincodePattern = /^\d{6}$/;`.

thanks.

Comment: *it is also accepting letter "e"* I'm extremely doubtful. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Yeah: 1e10 is allowed in \d - change to [0-9]

Comment: @mplungjan I'd be very interested if you could reproduce that because `/^\d{6}$/.test('1e10')` produces `false` for me

Comment: @mplungjan—perhaps you omitted the sarcasm emoji… :-/

Comment: `/^\d{6}$/.test(1e5)` return `true`. 
`/^\d{6}$/.test("1e5")` return `false`

Comment: Because `1e5` is not a **string**. When converted to a string, it is `"100000"`

Comment: So `.test` coerces numbers to strings, interesting.

Comment: @Phil exactly! there is nothing wrong with the regex, OP needs to check what he has fed into the regex.

Comment: @CertainPerformance—per [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-regexp.prototype.test): *3. Let string be ? ToString(S).* ;-)

Comment: @mplungjan i have tried this(`[0-9]`) but still it is accepting letter "e". thanks...

Comment: @Phil Drat - it sounded plausible. I however think that it is the underlying issue. The coercion to number before he tests

Comment: @RobG See `3. Let string be ? ToString(S).` - the input apparently does not need to be a string. I was surprised, I would have thought `/^\d{6}$/.test(555555)` would have thrown a `TypeError` or something

Comment: @CertainPerformance—internally, 1e10 is a number, that representation is just in the code, the actual value isn't that literally. `1e4.toString()` gives "10000".

Comment: OP must be taking the string input and running it through `Number(stringInput)`. That's the only way (so far) I've been able to see this happening

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ep6zqja5/  `var pincodePattern = /^\d{6}$/
var test1 = "3e5"
console.log(test1,pincodePattern.test(test1));
console.log(+test1, pincodePattern.test(+test1));
`

Comment: PLEASE post the COMPLETE relevant code in a [mcve] with the input field and the event handler. Click the `<>` and create a snippet

Comment: @CertainPerformance—one of the good parts of JS (probably a bad part according to Crockford) is that where the value of an argument to a built–in method must be of a certain type, it is first coerced into that type. The only case where `ToString(value)` will throw a TypeError is where the Type of *value* is Symbol (per  [*ToString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-tostring)).